# Domain Model Diagram Inclusion

Tags: java, uml

I'm developing a database application using the MVC pattern. I've produced a domain model (platform independent) which contains my all my entities but I'm a bit confused if I should include my Database class in the domain model too. Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: If you think it makes your documentation better, do it. If you think it makes your documentation worse, don't.

Comment: What do you mean by a platform independent domain model? Problem domain or solution domain? If you mean the former, surely it should not be polluted by a database class.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the Models is to organize diagrams. It is not a rule to be strictly followed.

One is at liberty to even create your own model and place it charts you want.
For example, in my project, I have a model called Data Model, and in this I put the Entity Relationship Diagram of my database.

As JB Nizet says, if you helps you and makes you easy documentation do. And if you want to place it elsewhere, too.

Make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your database model is the M from MVC. It's a fairly good idea to include the database design in your model. Here the MDG approach pays off. On the domain level you must be quite abstract regarding the database model you use. Usually you will just have a domain model as simple classes. When you go down towards development you refine that model and derive concrete database tables (which in turn can be modeled as stereotyped classes). It's a good idea to have a <> relation between the concrete tables and the more abstract domain classes.